# How to change drush drupal folder

Tags: drush

i install 3 drupal site without drush in xampp localhost in ubuntu and now install drush. how to use drush with 3 drupal local site???
first drupal site in dr7 folder
second drupal site in drupal7 folder
third drupal site in mydrupal folder

Answer (score 3):

Install Drush globally, and ensure that it is in your `$PATH`. Assuming that you have used Composer to install your site-local Drush, then you may run the global `drush` command, select the site you want to use either via an alias (`@exampleorg`) or commandline options (`--root=/path/to/drupal --uri=http://example.org`), and Drush will automatically redispatch to the site-local copy.  You may use different versions of Drush in your different local sites, if you wish, and it will still work correctly.